# Start rabbitmq configured spring boot application, without having rabbitmq installed locally

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

As I work in a team, not everyone needs to have rabbitmq installed in their system. But the application needs rabbitmq configured as we need to listen to some messages. Is there any way using which the application can start even when the rabbitmq is not installed locally?

application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
rabbitmq.queue=sample_queue
rabbitmq.queue.order=order
rabbitmq.queue.order_item=order_item
rabbitmq.queue.facility=facility
rabbitmq.exchange=sample_exchange
rabbitmq.exchange.order=order
rabbitmq.exchange.order_item=order_item
rabbitmq.exchange.facility=facility
rabbitmq.routingKey=sample_routing_key
rabbitmq.routingKey.order=order.#
rabbitmq.routingKey.order_item=order_item.#
rabbitmq.routingKey.facility=facility.#
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.default-requeue-rejected=false
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval=3s
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=6
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-interval=10s
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.multiplier=2
```

RabbitMQConfiguration:

```
/**
     * order topic exchange.
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange orderTopicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(orderExchange);
    }

    /**
     * order_item topic exchange.
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange orderItemTopicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(orderItemExchange);
    }

    /**
     * facility topic exchange.
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange facilityTopicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(facilityExchange);
    }

    /**
     * dead letter order topic exchange.
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange deadLetterOrderTopicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(deadLetterOrderExchange);
    }

    /**
     * dead letter order_item topic exchange.
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange deadLetterOrderItemTopicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(deadLetterOrderItemExchange);
    }

    /**
     * dead letter facility topic exchange.
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange deadLetterFacilityTopicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(deadLetterFacilityExchange);
    }

    /**
     * order queue.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue orderQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(orderQueue)
                .withArgument(RabbitMqUtil.DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE, deadLetterOrderExchange)
                .withArgument(RabbitMqUtil.DEAD_LETTER_ROUTING_KEY, deadLetterOrderRoutingKey)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * order_item queue.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue orderItemQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(orderItemQueue)
                .withArgument(RabbitMqUtil.DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE, deadLetterOrderItemExchange)
                .withArgument(RabbitMqUtil.DEAD_LETTER_ROUTING_KEY, deadLetterOrderItemRoutingKey)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * facility queue.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue facilityQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(facilityQueue)
                .withArgument(RabbitMqUtil.DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE, deadLetterFacilityExchange)
                .withArgument(RabbitMqUtil.DEAD_LETTER_ROUTING_KEY, deadLetterFacilityRoutingKey)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * dead letter order queue.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue deadLetterOrderQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(deadLetterOrderQueue).build();
    }

    /**
     * dead letter order_item queue.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue deadLetterOrderItemQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(deadLetterOrderItemQueue).build();
    }

    /**
     * dead letter facility queue.
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue deadLetterFacilityQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(deadLetterFacilityQueue).build();
    }

    /**
     * order binding.
     */
    @Bean
    public Binding orderBinding() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(orderQueue());
        amqpAdmin.declareExchange(orderTopicExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(orderQueue()).to(orderTopicExchange()).with(orderRoutingKey);
    }

    /**
     * order_item binding.
     */
    @Bean
    public Binding orderItemBinding() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(orderItemQueue());
        amqpAdmin.declareExchange(orderItemTopicExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(orderItemQueue()).to(orderItemTopicExchange()).with(orderItemRoutingKey);
    }

    /**
     * facility binding.
     */
    @Bean
    public Binding facilityBinding() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(facilityQueue());
        amqpAdmin.declareExchange(facilityTopicExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(facilityQueue()).to(facilityTopicExchange()).with(facilityRoutingKey);
    }

    /**
     * dead letter order binding.
     */
    @Bean
    public Binding deadLetterOrderBinding() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(deadLetterOrderQueue());
        amqpAdmin.declareExchange(deadLetterOrderTopicExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterOrderQueue()).to(deadLetterOrderTopicExchange())
                .with(deadLetterOrderRoutingKey);
    }

    /**
     * dead letter order_item binding.
     */
    @Bean
    public Binding deadLetterOrderItemBinding() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(deadLetterOrderItemQueue());
        amqpAdmin.declareExchange(deadLetterOrderItemTopicExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterOrderItemQueue()).to(deadLetterOrderItemTopicExchange())
                .with(deadLetterOrderItemRoutingKey);
    }

    /**
     * dead letter facility binding.
     */
    @Bean
    public Binding deadLetterFacilityBinding() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(deadLetterFacilityQueue());
        amqpAdmin.declareExchange(deadLetterFacilityTopicExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterFacilityQueue()).to(deadLetterFacilityTopicExchange())
                .with(deadLetterFacilityRoutingKey);
    }

    /**
     * template.
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * creating connection factory to setup connection with rabbitmq.
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * messageConverter.
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Required for executing administration functions against an AMQP Broker.
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }
```

Getting this exception when trying to start the application without rabbitmq:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ul.lr.UrbanLadderLrApplication.main(UrbanLadderLrApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding]: Factory method 'orderBinding' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2095) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2068) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2048) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueue(RabbitAdmin.java:267) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ul.lr.integration.rabbitmq.config.RabbitMqConfig.orderBinding(RabbitMqConfig.java:180) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ul.lr.integration.rabbitmq.config.RabbitMqConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddcf4c35.CGLIB$orderBinding$19(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ul.lr.integration.rabbitmq.config.RabbitMqConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddcf4c35$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3c84e319.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ul.lr.integration.rabbitmq.config.RabbitMqConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddcf4c35.orderBinding(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1113) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:526) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50061', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How the rabbitMQ connection ia beeing configured? Can you provide It? Do you have the option to run the rabbitMQ with docker?

Comment: No, we cant run it with docker. Have edited the question, please check @FelipeBonfante

Comment: Try to use spring conditional property pra other similar conditional annotatiins on you rabbitMQ configuration. Here is the link for conditional on property https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

Comment: And you define the properties for local application without the property you put on conditional. Try this and let me know ir It worked for you